# how to use ldap for authentication for app in django?

Tags: django

I want to use LDAP authentication for my application. My application is taking the input from user and storing details such as firstname,lastname in database. When I write following code in my settings.py file but I didn't get any error for that and application is running normally. So how can I know that LDAP is using in app or need some modifications in app. Please help me. I used basic settings from Django documentation.

```
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, GroupOfNamesType
# Baseline configuration.
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://ldap.example.com"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "cn=django-agent,dc=example,dc=com"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "marksheet"
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=users,dc=example,dc=com",
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s)")
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=django,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com",
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(objectClass=groupOfNames)"
)
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = GroupOfNamesType(name_attr="cn")
AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP = "cn=enabled,ou=django,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com"
AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "first_name": "firstname",
    "last_name": "lastname",
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: Please reformat your question. Put an extra line break before the code block, and you can remove the backtick '`' before and after it. The backtick is generally used for inline code blocks. Also in your settings.py have you changed the URIs to actual ones where you LDAP server is (not the example.com shown in your code)? My guess is nothing will happen unless the AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI etc point to a real LDAP server with a properly configured domain.

Comment: Thanks.i understand that i have to use ldap_server_uri actual ldap server . how to create user for ldap and how to know actual ldap server??main problem with configuration of ldapserver and connecting with django???

Comment: You should really reformat and rephrase your question. Your first question is how to setup LDAP. Then the next question is how to configure Django to use it for authentication. Anyway here is a pointer - http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin22/

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are trying to do this using the [django-auth-ldap](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-auth-ldap) package. For this setup, your settings are missing the most important part, namely adding `django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend` to your `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`.

Refer to the [django-auth-ldap documentation](http://packages.python.org/django-auth-ldap/) for more detailed setup instructions.